# getting rows with the highest value grouped by field from a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table

```
+----+----------+-----+
| id | priority | sub |
+----+----------+-----+
| 1  |    1     |  A  |
| 2  |    3     |  A  |
| 3  |    4     |  A  |
| 4  |    2     |  B  |
| 5  |    9     |  B  |
+----+----------+-----+
```

I'm trying to get the rows with the highest priority for each sub. So this result:

```
+----+----------+-----+
| id | priority | sub |
+----+----------+-----+
| 3  |    4     |  A  |
| 5  |    9     |  B  |
+----+----------+-----+
```

I tried grouping, but that gives unpredictable results. My guess was a nested query, first starting to find the highest priority like so:

```
select max(priority),sub from t group by sub
```

which gives me

```
+----------+-----+
| priority | sub |
+----------+-----+
|    4     |  A  |
|    9     |  B  |
+----------+-----+
```

But I also need the ID, adding to the query obviously gives me the wrong ID, joining this result with a query on the same table gave me an error (ER_NONUNIQ_TABLE(1066)), which makes sense... Anyone that can push me in the right direction?

Comment: `+1` for adding sample records with desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea behind the subquery is that it separately gets the maximum value of `PRIORITY` for each `SUB`. The result of which will then be joined back to the original table.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  sub, max(priority) maxVal
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP BY sub
        ) b ON a.sub = b.sub AND
                a.priority = b.maxVal
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75c50/5)